# How can I store data as a HashMap online?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-datastore, cloud

this is my first time I am trying to bring a project I made to the App Store. Basically, my project matches university students with complementary course expertise. So, I List what I can tutor, and put what I want Tutoring for. Then my program finds the best match for you. I do this by storing all the members in a series of hashmaps. The first hashmap takes in the course I need a tutor for, and maps me to another hashmap which takes the course I can tutor, and returns the highest priority member. It’s written in Java and I have I working on my computer. Basically, how do I store this hashmap online so that my app can find matches from any device?

This is just the first issue I ran into while trying to make this project public on the App Store. Continued help would be extrmeley appreciated.

Comment: Use any database like couch db, redis, mongo db

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reading some tutorials and watching some videos on Firebase: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/firebase/

Then after this, you will want to know how to add Firebase to your Android project. This can be done like this:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
```

And also check out this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

You're basically going to add this data to a database stored with columns Hashmap "Keys" and "Values."

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to go with AWS for any reason, S3 will easily handle your needs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html

Example of a bucket:

> A bucket is a container for objects stored in Amazon S3. Every object
>   is contained in a bucket. For example, if the object named
>   photos/puppy.jpg is stored in the johnsmith bucket, then it is
>   addressable using the URL
>   http://johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com/photos/puppy.jpg
>
> Buckets serve several purposes: they organize the Amazon S3 namespace
>   at the highest level, they identify the account responsible for
>   storage and data transfer charges, they play a role in access control,
>   and they serve as the unit of aggregation for usage reporting.